# Lotus Notes: Dialog list - refresh fields on keyword change not working

Tags: refresh, field, lotus-notes

I have a dialog list which use `Use View dialog for Choices`.

I have a row in a table which its appearing depends on the value selected from that dialog list. ( I am using `Hide when formula`... ) The form has `Automatically refresh fields` checked.

The problem is that after I select a certain value from the dialog list, and I even had selected `Refresh fields on keyword change` property, I MUST hit `F5` or just `TAB` ( to go to a next field ) in order to make that row table to appear. I also tried to add `uidoc.Refresh` at the `Exiting`/`OnChange` event(s) of the dialog list.

I have noticed the following:

- the refresh works fine for  `combo box, list box, radio button` or `check box`
- the refresh works fine for `dialog list` where you are using a list of choices / formula.
- the refresh doesn't work for `dialog list` where you are using view dialog for choices ( my case ).

Is there any solution for this issue? I want when I selected a value from the dialog list, immediately the row / line should appear/disappear.

Thank for your time!

Comment: It looks like this has been a known "issue" for quite some time and IBM have not actioned a fix. Which version of Notes are you using? This post relates to 8.0.1 - http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd8forum.nsf/7756aedc25e6d81285256324005ac76c/643db070a1dc91f98525749000728bd4?OpenDocument